# Default "use" action and "website" object being created automatically

Tags: facebook, api, open-graph-beta

What is the default "use" action mean for Open Graph? I deleted the action multiple times but it keeps coming back, along with the "website" object. Also, according to the Open Graph section of insights, there are hundreds of these actions happening everyday.

Does anyone have any insight as to what this action means and how these actions are being generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every app is getting default objects and actions. You know those "social discovery stories" that you can turn on and off in the FB developer settings? These are Open Graph stories saying that the user "used" an "app", or "played" a "game". I think, theoretically, you could also create your own aggregations around this data if that was somehow interesting for you.

Most app developers like having those social discovery stories turned on because it helps get them more users, but some developers would prefer their apps to run 'privately' for their users. If that is your case, then I'm not sure whether or not these objects do anything once 'social discovery' is turned off.